# Justification for a step in the derivative transform of infinitesimal transformation

Tags: calculus, symmetry, infinitesimals

When I was looking through p23-24 of *Symmetry Analysis of Differential Equations* by Daniel J. Arrigo, I wasn’t sure why we can do this:
$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dx} + [Y_x+Y_yy’]\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2) }{1+[X_x+X_yy’]\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)}=(\frac{dy}{dx} + [Y_x+Y_yy’]\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2))( 1-[X_x+X_yy’]\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2))  $$

Can anyone explain why we can do this in the intermediate step?

Comment: If $\epsilon$ is mall you can do this because $(1+\epsilon)(1-\epsilon)$ is close to what ?